# Mailchimp API v3.0 add subscriber to segment, not displaying in admin

Tags: php, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am trying to add a user that is in the list to a segment using [drewm's Mailchimp php API wrapper](https://github.com/drewm/mailchimp-api)

Creating the segment if it doesn't exist works fine, and it displays in the MailChimp environment. If I then try to add a subscriber using `POST /lists/{list_id}/segments/{segment_id}`, the API responds like it should, stating that the subscriber has been added to the segment, or telling me the subscriber hasn't been added if the subscriber is already in the segment. But in the MailChimp admin, the segment still displays as empty. Here is my code, I have no idea where I'm going wrong:

```
// Segmentation
// Check if event has segment linked, if not, create segment and add to post meta
$event_segment = get_post_meta($event->post_id, 'byron_mailchimp_segment', true);

if (empty($event_segment)) {
    // Create new segment,
    $create_segment_response = $MailChimp->post('/lists/' . $event_list . '/segments/', [
        'name' => 'Aangemeld',
        'static_segment' => [],
    ]);

    $event_segment = $create_segment_response['id'];
    // Save segment ID to post meta
    add_post_meta($event->post_id, 'byron_mailchimp_segment', $event_segment);
}

$add_to_segment_response = $MailChimp->post('/lists/' . $event_list . '/segments/' . $event_segment, [
    'members_to_add' => [$member['user_email']],
]);

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($add_to_segment_response);
echo "</pre>";
```

I've already checked if the $event_segment contains the right ID, and it does.

Comment: Highly possible this is just cache stuff! I've experienced something like this before, and it shows up a few minutes later. Maybe try the API playground for extra confirmation that it's indeed there, while you wait!

Comment: This must be the issue here. In the API playground it indeed confirms the subscribers have been added to the segment. I had a feeling it had something to do with caching, but it's been an hour and I've still not seen any change, that got me worried. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yeah, an hour is certainly not normal. Maybe you can also look "around" the problem by searching up the user's email and seeing if the segment's reflected on their individual entry? That wouldn't likely be cached, would it?

Comment: The subscribers now have showed up in the segment when viewing from the admin panel. It must have been a caching thing, like you suggested. Thanks again!

Comment: Cool. Gonna copypasta this into an answer in case others with similar questions come looking and see an 'unanswered' question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probable that this is a caching issue!

I've experienced something like this before, and it always shows up up a few minutes to an hour later.

Two suggestions to help diagnose:

1. Try the [API playground](https://api.mailchimp.com/playground/) for extra confirmation that it's indeed there, while you wait!
2. You may also be able to look "around" the problem by searching up the user's email and seeing if the segment's reflected on their individual entry. That wouldn't likely be cached.